# r trycatch for conduct a forever loop for web crawling Q

Tags: r, web-crawler

I recently learn to web crawling.

I use the While(TRUE) to let my function of web crawling to run forever.

However, my internet is not stable, so it sometimes shows error when my internet failed.

I tried to figure it out use the trycatch function

rf() is my function of web crawling.

```
if(tryCatch(rf(), error=function(cond) FALSE)==FALSE){
  Sys.sleep(60+sample(1:5,1))
  rf()
}
```

I ask R to run it again after a while because the Internet usually would be fine after a while.

However, this code is not good enough because if the internet failed for the second time  then R stop.

I thought if i use repeat and it might be better, as followed.

Am I right?

```
repeat {
if(tryCatch(rf(), error=function(cond) FALSE)==FALSE){
  Sys.sleep(60+sample(1:5,1))
  rf()
} 
Sys.sleep(900+sample(1:30,1))#second
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait a longer time period if the requests fails, try this code:

```
while(TRUE) {
  tryCatch({
    rf()
    print("wait normal")
    Sys.sleep(60+sample(1:5,1))
  }, error = function(e) { 
    print("wait longer") 
    Sys.sleep(900+sample(1:30,1))
    }
  )
}
```

Note that your rf() function must be in a try statement so that errors are catched and not raised further.

Answer (score 0):

May be simple `try` in `while(TRUE)`

Like

```
e <- simpleError("test error")
while(T){
  try(stop(e))
  Sys.sleep(2)
  print(1)

}
```

but try your function